# netcore dependency injection per user

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am wondering how to set up the netcore dependency container for mvc with one instance per user.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options there are currently only three methods of specifying a lifetime: singleton(one instance per application),  scoped (one instance shared within a HttpRequest), transient (one instance per DI instance request)

Has someone attempted to do create on instance per user yet? I would be curious how it's done - if not i will probably dig through the docs at some point to see how it can be done and share the solution.

Comment: You do an instance per request(and not per user). The instance are available throughout the lifetime of the request. Can you elaborate on how you want to use the instance?

Comment: Essentially i have a login controller, where i input the credentials of a rest api. These rest client instances are initialized with the credentials passed upon login. hence my plan would be to use the factory register for the instance using the login information i store within the claims identity once per user. While this already does work on a per scope/per request base it is sub optimal in terms of performance.

Comment: (1) Memory caching with timeout; (2) Singleton-scoped dictionary with some token as a key (session id?) - you need manual cleanup; (3) [CookieTempData](https://luisfsgoncalves.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/cookie-based-tempdata-for-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I'm interested in the exact same question @Dbl , If you got a solution for this issue, can you please share it with me?

Comment: I'd consider adding this feature to my multitenancy library: https://github.com/dazinator/Dotnettency if there is enough interest. Please raise an issue there if you want me to look at it. I already create per tenant containers. I could add a hook that runs after a user authenticates. I could store the container in a memory cache, using sliding expiry, key'd by some user property ooke session I'd or username. If the user closes there browser as the cache is sliding the container would eventually be disposed.

Answer (score 2):

Create instance on first user request and keep it alive (for next requests) until with some expiration timeout... This looks like a [Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state#a-working-sample-using-session).

You may register your service with factory method and analyze current Session inside.

Comment: while that would certainly work i don't want to offload dependency injection related services into the session. I will keep it in mind though.

Comment: Be honest with yourself - you are looking for something to mix DI and sessions. No matter how you name it - it's true. It's user-scoped. You can implement it in different ways - say, create your own "Scope" (in terms of DI) and put it into Session and resolve other services from this scope, but will you still using "some session" mechanism that use memory per user, will not work in webfarm (you can't serialize service and share it between several processes/machines) and so on. If you don't like this (it's bad for scaling) - may be you should review/rethink your architecture?

Comment: While i partially agree with you i still don't want to mix it. DI breaking from disabling session would be an unexpected aftermath, when in fact all my DI is supposed to depend on is a unique request identity.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an asp.net core application, middleware that is automatically added to the middleware pipeline handles creating a new DI scope at the start of a request, and disposing of that scope at the end of a request. This scope is stored in HttpContext. This scope will be used when injecting MVC controllers etc. Therefore if you want to have per-user services injected into your MVC controllers / action methods, you'll need to replace this scope in HttpContext with your own one built for the current user. You'd have to do this with middleware which would have to run after the authentication middleware (so after the current user was established). Your custom middleware would look at the current authenticated user, and the GetOrCreate the IServiceProvider (container) held in some cache with probably a sliding expiry. With the per user IServiceProvider in hand, it would then create a scope for the current request and replace the scope currently in HttpContext with this user specific one, also ensuring its disposed of at the end of the request. The thing is, when building the per user container, if you create a new ServiceCollection for each user and register a few services and build and cache that IServiceProvider for that user, you won't be able to resolve any services that you've only registered at the application level I.e on startup. This is where the concept of child containers are handy, which microsoft doesnt implement out of the box, but you can use if you switch to using another DI provider like Autofac. Autofac provides an implementation of IServiceProvider and the ability to spawn child containers. If you used this mechanism you could create a child container for each user, which means it would still be able to resolve all your higher level services, but now you can also resolve the user specific services. If you do all this, you'll be able to have per user services injected.

It's a fair amount of work. If there is enough interest I'd consider adding this feature to my multitenancy library as it already does something similar to create per tenant containers: https://github.com/dazinator/Dotnettency

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
    var shoppingLists = new Dictionary < string,
ShoppingListStateContainer > ();

services.AddTransient < ShoppingListStateContainer > (s = >{
    var userName = s.GetRequiredService < AuthenticationStateProvider > ().GetAuthenticationStateAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().User.Identity.Name ? ?"null";
    lock(s) {
        if (!shoppingLists.ContainsKey(userName)) shoppingLists.Add(userName, new ShoppingListStateContainer());
    }
    return shoppingLists[userName];
});
```